# Passing a URL which includes an ampersand from Javascript to PHP to a MySQL data bsae

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

**Objective:**

I am trying to place a URL into a MySQL database.
The URL contains many special characters. 
The specific character that causes a problem is the & character. (The process works correctly as long as there is no & character in the string).

I pass the URL from JavaScript to a PHP script.

The URL starts out as http://www.example.com/?def&ghi in the Javascript.

I then code

```
rssURL = encodeURIComponent(rssURL);           // perform encode
```

which displays the following value in the console.log

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%3Fdef%26ghi%20
```

I send the URL to the PHP script using the following code in the Javascript

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "updatecontent.php", true); 
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                
xhr.send(userdata);
```

The userdata variable contains:

```
“datastring” = username^password^rssURL^ varX^ varY
```

In the PHP script, I have the following code

```
 $URLgroup= $_POST['datastring'];
 $datalist = explode ('^', $URLgroup); 
 $ws_user      = $datalist[0];
 $ws_pass      = $datalist[1];
 $ws_urlX       = $datalist[2]; 
  // this is the rssURL element passed from the Javascript
 $ws_url        = rawurldecode ($ws_urlX);   //  perform decode 
 $ws_title     = $datalist[3];
 $ws_category = $datalist[4];
```

I place the URL in the data base using the following code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO global_feeds_table (global_feed_category,    global_feed_name, global_feed_title, global_feed_link) 
       VALUES ( '$ws_category', '$ws_div_id', '$ws_title', '$ws_url') ";
```

The data base field called `global_feed_link` now contains the following URL

```
           http://www.example.com/?def&amp;ghi
```

The URL should just contain an “&” (after “def”  and before “ghi”)  BUT it also has “amp;”  after the & character  THIS IS THE  PROBLEM

**Environment:**

- Using UTF8 encoding throughout
- Windows 10
- Google Chrome Version 40
- Dreamweaver 5 (IDE)

Comment: Try using urlencode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)  on the php side and remove the encodeURIComponent from the javascript side.

Comment: I maybe missed some thing what was the reason of passing url to javascript and after that to php, why not directly to php?

Comment: Are you getting the value of $ws_url varibale &amp; or & ?

Comment: I must encode prior to the execution of the EXPLODE statement; other wise the EXPLODE will not process any data in the string after the & sign (which will cause an invalid index error when trying to reference $ws_title and $ws_category. Are you suggesting that I encode the entire $URLgroup variable before the EXPLODE statement ?    The javascript performs a variety of other functions before calling the PHP script.

Comment: After further debugging :
 (1) The $_POST statement in the PHP script automatically decoded the &URLgroup string. It converted the %26 to &amp;  
(2) Based on a var_dump to the console.log, the $ws_url contains <http://www.example.com/?def&amp;ghi>
(3) When echo-ing back $ws_url to the HTML form (via the Javascript), the HTML form would display $ws_url as <http://www.example.com/def&ghi>   
(4) When doing a substr_count of $ws_url in the PHP script looking for "amp" , it found NO matches. When looking for "&", it found one match. 
I am still uncertain about the encode/decode functionality.